# How can I hide a script src?

Tags: html

I host a website, and I need to hide a script src. For example, 
    script src="main.js"
would need to be
    script src="main.js"
but it would be unclickable. I realize this isn't the most well phrased question, but how can I keep the user from seeing the JavaScript?

Comment: You can't. Don't bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't present JavaScript to the browser and then hide it from the user; it's just not possible. The best you can do is obfuscate it and make it difficult for the casual observer to decipher, however it won't stop a determined user from de-obfuscating it.

Comment: I settled on this. Soon after posting the question, I looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript), and found [this](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx), which I suppose will work. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I found a node.js npm plugin that can hide any src="*" & href + content
https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-hide

This works also for php href, src, content it will use everything inside src=""

You need only node.js for creating the exported files. It´s easy to use even if you don´t know node.js. You can watch youtube guides for installing and using node.js
If you create enviroment 1 time you can load cool stuff with npm

It turns

```
<script src="test/folder/sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

into

```
<script src="TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq" rel="stylesheet">
```

And it generate new jquery include codes like this to include your scripts with javascript in a external file

```
$('[src=\'TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR\']').attr("src", "test/folder/sample.js")  
$('[href=\'gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq\']').attr("src", "test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css")
```

Also I would suggest you that you include all of your external javascript codes in 1 single js file. This file you place in the root of your index file that you can make this

```
<script src="./allinone_external_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then make right htaccess that nobody can acces this file. You can also make a fake import script for the source code that every body can see. But this file is only a redirect for the real external js file. you make this multiple times as example + use other obfuscation tools. This will protect you from people searching exploits with your javascript codes. I know its no big deal and maybe you can see the jquery include codes if you know how. But anyway its a great protection.